# jquery not working after async postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

i am doing async postback using updatepanel. after async postback jQuery functionality not working.I'm using jQuery to wire up some mousedown mouseenter effects on html table cells that are inside an UpdatePanel. The events are bound in $(document).ready

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function ()



     {
    $(".csstablelisttd").mousedown(function (e)
                        {
    //mouse down code
    });
 $(".csstablelisttd").mouseenter(function (e)
                        {
    //mouse entercode
    });
                        $("#contentPlaceHolderMain_btnFix").click(function (e)
                        {alert("Alert");//here alert is generate two times an then postback occurs
                           //btn click code
                        }
                    }

            </script>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelTableAppointment" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
         <table id="table" runat="server">
             //table data
            </table>

                        </ContentTemplate><Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFix" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: If i'm not wrong, an async postback doesn't fire the ready event for jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`asp:UpdatePanel` replaces the content with the result returned from the server. This means all hooked events previously will not work after a post back.

Use [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $("#table").on("mousedown mouseenter", ".csstablelisttd", function (e) {
        //mouse down AND mouse enter code
    });

    $("#contentPlaceHolderMain_btnFix").on("click", function (e) {
        alert("Alert");//here alert is generate two times an then postback occurs
        //btn click code
    });
});
</script>
```

*Note: if your mouse down and mouse enter code are different, split them out.*

Do the same for every event hook you include that will exist within the `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: I've already updated with an example. Does it make sense? Let me know if you would like me to further expand.

Comment: The `.live()` function has been deprecated for months, and shouldn't be used. If you're using 1.7.x+, use `.on()` otherwise use `.delegate()`. If you're using a version of jQuery that's so old it doesn't have `.delegate()`, probably a good idea to update.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Good point - I'll update the example. I'm worried `.on()` might confuse the OP as per my updated example, but I hope it will make sense if I just type the whole thing out.

Comment: I would like to add that even when using the hooks, it is not working. jquery does not work after the async postback

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add event handler for ajax endRequest provided by Toolkit. Read more over [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx)

**Add In Javascript block that executes on page load.**

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandle);

function endRequestHandle(sender, Args)
{
     alert("After ajax call");
}
```

Comment: In endRequestHandle(sender, Args) what i use document.ready function or what

Comment: If you do not get the binding in endRequestHandle then make a function that do initialization like bindings etc and call from both $(document).ready and endRequestHandle